# Click ImageButton

Tags: android, click, imagebutton

I have one question.

There are 4 ImageButtons(a1, a2 and b1, b2). You can chose only a1 or a2 and never both at the same time. Should I check each click on these buttons?

How can I do this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: No idea what platform you are using.

Comment: sorry,i forgot to write - android

Comment: Something like this?  if(v.isPressed()|| dp.isPressed()){
 rect.setClickable(false);
 circ.setClickable(false);
}

Answer (score 0):

There is one easy way to do this:

when you click one button set enablet to false to other button and against.

Code:

```
b1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
   public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
      if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)b2.setEnabled(false);
      else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)b2.setEnabled(true);
   }
});

b2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
   public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
      if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)b1.setEnabled(false);
      else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)b1.setEnabled(true);
   }
});
```